# Use 2008 R2 and 2003 server domain and LDAP with Windows 8.1 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have two server domain one with Windows Server 2003 server and other Windows Server 2008 R2.

With this can I use Windows 8.1 and 10 clients to connect with domain and apply policies?

Comment: So you have two AD domains? Or one?

Comment: two in redundancy

Answer (score 0):

If you got Two DC for the same domain you could join your windows 8.1 and 10 to your only domain and apply policies.

one computer could only join one domain, if you got two different domain and each DC manage only one of yours domain you would need a trust beetween your domain and manage your policy in the whole AD Forest.

NB : for your client you would need the 8.1 and 10 professional edition because Microsoft doesn't allow Home editions of Windows to join domains because they figure that home users won't be connecting to any type of domain. Although that does suck, you do have to purchase the professional version of Windows in order to get that feature.